# Raise onchange event html input file from button

Tags: javascript, onchange

I would like raise the onchange event of the input file type by clicking a button:

Example:

```
<input id="File1" type="file" onchange="show(this)"  />
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" onclick="butclick()" />
<input id="Button2" type="button" value="button" onclick="document.getElementById('File1').onchange()" />
<input id="Button3" type="button" value="button" onclick="document.getElementById('Button1').onclick()" />
```

---

```
<script>
function butclick() {
    alert('yes');
}
</script>
```

I can trigger the click event of another button but not the onchange event of an input file.

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend to write all your Javascript code into the script tags to have everything on one place.

The "change" event is triggered, when the element (in you case input type file) changes and not by clicking another element

For example:

```
function handleFileInput() {
 console.log("change event of file input triggered.");   
}

document.getElementById("files").addEventListener("change", handleFileInput, true);
```

In this example the change event is attached to the file input and when the user chose a file the event is dispatched.

You can try the code on jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/883LL/1/

---

But if you really want to dispatch the event by clicking a button you could try with dispatchEvent:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.dispatchEvent

Hope this helps!

Comment: +1 for using `addEventListener` instead of inline JS.

Comment: cant I trigger the change event thru a button or div click. Thats what I want to do. Thank you